# What does constructor do in this line?

Tags: c++

There is the simple code, that i found in c++ tutorial. But I can't understand this line:

```
c1 = Complex(10.0);
```

In comments was written that constructor can be used to convert from one type to another. Can somebody explain this moment. Thank you for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex
{
  public:
    Complex() : dReal(0.0), dImag(0.0)
    { cout << "invoke default constructor" << endl;}
    /*explicit*/ Complex(double _dReal)
      : dReal(_dReal), dImag(0.0)
    { cout << "invoke real constructor " << dReal <<endl;}
    Complex(double _dReal, double _dImag)
      : dReal(_dReal), dImag(_dImag)
    {
        cout << "invoke complex constructor " << dReal
             << ", " << dImag << endl;
    }

    double dReal;
    double dImag;
};

int main(int argcs, char* pArgs[])
{
    Complex c1, c2(1.0), c3(1.0, 1.0);

    // constructor can be used to convert from one type
    // to another
    c1 = Complex(10.0);

    // the following conversions work even if explicit
    // is uncommented
    c1 = (Complex)20.0;
    c1 = static_cast<Complex>(30.0);

    // the following implicit conversions work if the
    // explicit is commented out
    c1 = 40.0;
    c1 = 50;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably that the double value 10.0d is converted into a complex number with the real part equal to 10.0d and the imaginary part equal to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This right here:

```
Complex(double _dReal)
      : dReal(_dReal), dImag(0.0)
    { cout << "invoke real constructor " << dReal <<endl;}
```

is a constructor which will take `double` and it will create `Complex` object from it. You can see that it will set the real part (`dReal`) to the value passed to the constructor (`_dReal`), and it will setup the imaginary part to the 0.

This line:

```
c1 = Complex(10.0);
```

will call that constructor, and it will **convert** passed real number (`10.0`) into the `Complex` object.

**Edit:** Please note that this is not the real conversion - it is explicitly creation of the `Complex` object by passing the double to it - you have examples of the conversions in the answer provided by dasblinkedlight.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a conversion, because construct a `Complex` object explicitly:

```
c1 = Complex(10.0);
```

This, however, is a conversion:

```
c1 = (Complex)20.0;
```

and so is this:

```
c1 = static_cast<Complex>(30.0);
```

Both conversions above would work even if the constructor is explicit, because they invoke conversion, ...well, explicitly.

The other two would not work with an explicit constructor:

```
c1 = 40.0;
c1 = 50;
```

Here the conversion is implicit, i.e. the operation is implied by the type of the left-hand side of the assignment, and the presence of a constructor taking an expression on the right-hand side. The compiler cannot apply the constructor declared `explicit` in situations like this, so if you uncomment `explicit` in the declaration above, this snippet is not going to compile.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
c1 = Complex(10.0);
```

calls in fact this:

```
Complex(double _dReal)
  : dReal(_dReal), dImag(0.0)
{
    cout << "invoke real constructor " << dReal <<endl;
}
```

This constructor just initializes the member `dReal` with the value passed in param and initializes `dImag` to  `0.0`.

When they say that you can convert one type to another, I guess they want to say that you can "convert" `double` to `Complex`.

Answer (score 1):

`c1 = Complex(10.0);` creates a `Complex` object and copies it to `c1`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `T(x)` for any given type `T` and object `x` (or objects `x1,x2...`) creates a temporary of type `T` constructed with the given arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`c1 = Complex(10.0);` calls your implicit constructor `/*explicit*/ Complex(double _dReal)`

The comment says that you can convert `double` to `Complex` type.

In your case with explicit being removed, you are allowed to declare `Complex c1 = 10.0 ;` which will implicitly call `Complex(double _dReal)` for you. If explicit was not commented, however, it would forbid 'automatic' conversion, and you would be forced to declare `Complex( 10.0 )` in order to 'convert' from `double` to `Complex`.